# Check for errors in ajax before submit form

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#userid").blur(function(){
        $.post("validation.php?input=userid",{ userid:$("#userid").val() } ,function(data){
            if(data == "blank"){
                $("#useridError").removeClass().addClass('messageError').html('Please do not leave blank!');
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Hello guys, I have this codes that use jQuery to validate the userid. There will be some more validation for example password, name, etc. But I am so confused. Now I am able to tell the user that the inserted userid contains error. When it comes to posting the form, how could I check the errors?

for example, the userid and name get errors, so when we click submit, the form will not submit. If there is no error displayed, then the form can be submitted.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#userid").blur(function(){
        $.post("validation.php?input=userid",{ userid:$("#userid").val() } ,function(data){
            if(data == "blank"){
                $("#useridError").removeClass().addClass('messageError').html('Please do not leave blank!');
                return false;
            }
        });

    });
     $("#useremail").blur(function(){
        $.post("validation.php?input=useremail",{ useremail:$("#useremail").val() } ,function(data){
            if(data == "blank"){
                $("#useremailError").removeClass().addClass('messageError').html('Please do not leave blank!');
                return false;
            }
        });

    });
     $("#username").blur(function(){
        $.post("validation.php?input=username",{ username:$("#username").val() } ,function(data){
            if(data == "blank"){
                $("#useremailError").removeClass().addClass('messageError').html('Please do not leave blank!');
                return false;
            }
        });

    });
});*/

function validate_userid(){
    $.post("validation.php?input=userid",{ userid:$("#userid").val() } ,function(data){
            if(data == "blank"){
                $("#useridError").removeClass().addClass('messageError').html('Please do not leave blank!');
                return false;
            }
        });
}
function validate_useremail(){
    $.post("validation.php?input=useremail",{ useremail:$("#useremail").val() } ,function(data){
            if(data == "blank"){
                $("#useremailError").removeClass().addClass('messageError').html('Please do not leave blank!');
                return false;
            }
        });
}

function validate_username(){
    $.post("validation.php?input=username",{ username:$("#username").val() } ,function(data){
            if(data == "blank"){
                $("#useremailError").removeClass().addClass('messageError').html('Please do not leave blank!');
                return false;
            }
        });
}
function validate(){
var userid = $("#userid").val();
var useremail = $("#useremail").val();
var username = $("#username").val();
if(userid == ""){
    validate_userid();
}else if(useremail == ""){
    validate_useremail();
}else if(username == ""){
    validate_username();
}
}

/*You can use any one of the validate()--------------the two are working as same-------------------*/
function validate(){
    var userid = $("#userid").val();
    var useremail = $("#useremail").val();
    var username = $("#username").val();
    if(userid == ""){
        $.post("validation.php?input=userid",{ userid:$("#userid").val() } ,function(data){
            if(data == "blank"){
                $("#useridError").removeClass().addClass('messageError').html('Please do not leave blank!');
                return false;
            }
        });
    }else if(useremail == ""){
        $.post("validation.php?input=useremail",{ useremail:$("#useremail").val() } ,function(data){
            if(data == "blank"){
                $("#useremailError").removeClass().addClass('messageError').html('Please do not leave blank!');
                return false;
            }
        });
    }else if(username == ""){
        $.post("validation.php?input=username",{ username:$("#username").val() } ,function(data){
            if(data == "blank"){
                $("#useremailError").removeClass().addClass('messageError').html('Please do not leave blank!');
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}

</script>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" value="" onblur="return validate_userid();" />
<div id="useridError"></div>

<input type="text" name="useremail" id="useremail" value="" onblur="return validate_useremail();" />
<div id="useremailError"></div>

<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" onblur="return validate_username();" />
<div id="usernameError"></div>

   <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="return validate();" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i am using the .blur function to give a better user interface to the user. when the focus is moved, the message will be displayed directly to the user instead of filling up all forms, click submit button, and display error message.

Comment: just put `return false;` after this `$("#useridError").removeClass().addClass('messageError').html('Please do not leave blank!');` in your code.

Comment: besides userid, I will do some more validation which will be $.post("#name").blur()....... I mean, let say I am filling up the email address, and got problem, when I move to name textfield, the error will be displayed beside email address text field. so i want to prevent the form from being submitted if there is any error message showed.

Comment: actually i want to do some kind of live validation

Comment: if there is no error, then i need to put return true?? and should i put anything like onclick function for the submit button?

Comment: return true is not needed.but you must check this validation for onclick for the submit button...........

Comment: ok now the onblur function is working just like the previous one. So now, back to submitting the form. how to submit the form? confused....

Comment: i think i should go for your previous codes which click the submit button and check all the forms. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can check values using `Regex` as follow

**SCRIPT**

```
var ck_name = 'YourDesiredRegExForValidation';//set your desired Regex to validate your `name`

function validate(form){
   var name = form.name.value;
   //set your all field's value in a variable
   var errors = [];

 if (!ck_name.test(name)) {
  errors[errors.length] = "You valid Name .";
 }
 //simultaneously check out all fields

 if (errors.length > 0) {
      reportErrors(errors);
      return false;
 }
  return true;
}

// Following function is just to display Errors
function reportErrors(errors){
      var msg = "Please Enter Valide Data...\n";
      for (var i = 0; i<errors.length; i++) {
              var numError = i + 1;
              msg += "\n" + numError + ". " + errors[i];
      }
      alert(msg);
 }
```

Check out [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/03/perfect-javascript-form-validation.html)

Comment: Thanks, but i am using PHP.

Comment: @Bizarre you're most welcome..Please mark it as answer(by click on the white arrow beside answer), if it is helpful to you, so if some other got stuck in this issue will get the correct solution.check this FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: I'm using Kichu solution, and i am not able to vote up since doesn't have enough reputation. but thumbs up! thanks.

Comment: @Bizarre its great to here that you find your issue resolved..cheer up

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, if the data does not pass validation, let the function return false; returning false will prevent the form from posting the data to the server; if the data does pass validation, let the function return true. 
   I can explain further, but basically, that's what needs to happen. 
 
   Hope this helps.